# Display Widgets Horizontally in Area

Tags: widgets

I am building a custom bootstrap 3 theme. I have created a new widget area for my header and am trying to get the widgets there to display horizontally, in line. I've looked up several tutorials, but none seem to be working. Can anyone help?

```
**Here is my CSS for the list:**

#top-widget-container ul { 
list-style-type: none; 
}

#top-widget-container ul li {
display: inline;
}

**And my functions.php widget insert**

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'add_header_widget' );
function add_header_widget() {

    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => 'Header Widget Area',
        'id' => 'header_widget',
        'before_widget' => '<li id="top-widget-container ul li">',
        'after_widget' => '</li>',
        'before_title' => '<h2 class="rounded">',
        'after_title' => '</h2>',
    ) );
}
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is no Bootstrap or CSS related site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for either `float` or `inline-block`.  For a variety of reasons, I prefer `inline-block`:

```
#top-widget-container ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    /* Next two lines make IE7 behave */
    zoom: 1;
    *display: inline;
    /* Adjust width to the appropriate size for your theme */
    width: 250px;
    /* Presumably you want all the widgets to align-top */
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Notice that I've used the "direct descendant" selector (aka child combinator selector or immediate child): `ul > li` - that way, any sub-lists don't get this same formatting (which could cause all sorts of challenges).  This selector is supported in modern browsers, IE8+, and IE7 (usually).

Alternatively, the float technique (don't like it as well, but will work):

```
#top-widget-container ul { 
    list-style-type: none; 
    /* Next two lines ensure the container clears the floats */
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#top-widget-container ul > li {
    display: block;
    /* Adjust width to the appropriate size for your theme */
    width: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Okay, with a minor tweak I was able to get it working. For some reason when the ul is after the class it doesn't work. I had to do ul#id and ul#id li. 

Thanks for the lesson on the ul > li. I didn't know that and I'm sure this will help me out alot!